iOS Widget Disappearing After App Updates
I've got these widgets available for users to choose from, which all work for some time. However, some users (including me, on my iPad only), are reporting that their widget disappears after app updates.
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI

@available(iOSApplicationExtension 15.0, *)
@main
struct QuoteDropletWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    var body: some Widget {
        QuoteDropletWidgetSmall()
        QuoteDropletWidgetWithIntentsMedium()
        QuoteDropletWidgetWithIntentsLarge()
        QuoteDropletWidgetMedium()
        QuoteDropletWidgetWithIntentsExtraLarge()
        QuoteDropletWidgetLarge()
        QuoteDropletWidgetExtraLarge()
    }
}

An example of one of these Widgets (they're all identical aside from size and isIntentsActive):
@available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.0, *)
struct QuoteDropletWidgetWithIntentsMedium: Widget {
    let kind: String = "QuoteDropletWidgetWithIntents"
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            QuoteDropletWidgetEntryView(entry: entry, isIntentsActive: true)
        }
        .disableContentMarginsIfNeeded() // Use the extension here
        .configurationDisplayName("Example Widget With Buttons")
        .description("Note that the color palette and font are customizable.")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemMedium])
    }
}

This is a new issue, from when I added more widget sizes and ones with intents (they were previously only displaying text, without intents I have now such as a 'like' button).
Old code:
struct QuoteDropletWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    var body: some Widget {
        QuoteDropletWidget()
    }
}

Could anyone point me to where in my code I should edit, such that widgets don't disappear (especially not after updates that don't even touch widgets)?

Is the "Kind" the same on all of those Widgets?

Can you clarify where it disappears? You mean like in Springboard, or on the Lock Screen? or it is no longer visible in the add widget UI?

@benc Once the user has added it to their home screen, it disappears off the home screen, but can be re-added.

@Meyssam Half are one string, and half are another string. Would you suggest I make the kind all the same, or all distinct?

I would‘ve guessed they must be distinct, so the System can tell them apart. Just a guess

I'm thinking it may be similar to this apple developer forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/746574?login=true
